# How to position my side bar menu exactly where I want it?

Tags: html, css

**Hello people!**

I'm very new to this site and to HTML... I would like to build my own website but since I don't have much experience and knowledge about HTML I need help. 

I want a side bar menu like on this website http://crichd.in/live/.  Can someone help me? Also I want the IPL T20 text on the top left like on the website. On the website the side bar menu and table is inside a div box. As I said, I'm very nooby :|.

Also, the last table content "wallpapers" Is a little bit too big... I set my custom size for it but it still is bigger then the other boxes. Can someone also fix this?

```
 <html>
    <title>IPLRADAR</TITLE>
    <head>
    <style>
    #cssmenu {
      background: #333;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 12em;
    }
    #cssmenu li {
      font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet      Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    #cssmenu a {
      background: #333;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
      color: #ccc;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 8px 12px;
       text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    #cssmenu a:hover {

    background: #2580a2 url("images/hover.gif") left center no-repeat;
      color: #fff;
      padding-bottom: 8px;
    }

    </style>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
    </style>
    <style>
    table, th, td { 
           border: 1px solid #CFD9BB;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    table-layout: fixed;

     </style>

<style> 
.div1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 750px;
    border: 2px solid black; 
    background: #CFD9BB
}
</style>
<style> 
.div2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0px solid black; 
    background: #F2F2F2
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
<center>

<table>
<tr>
<th style="background-color: #808080" width="500px">
<h3><font size="5" COLOR="blue" face="verdana">IPL</font><Font size ="5" color="white" face="verdana">T20</font></h3>
<div style="position: relative; top: -20px; left: 5px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; "><i>Free streams and news</i></th>
</tr></table>
<table>
<tr>
<td height="25px" width="500px" style="background-color: #F2F2F2; color:white;text-align:center">
<p><a href="stream.html"><font face ="verdana">Watch match (Stream)</a></font>
</td>
</tr>
<td height="25px" width="500px" style="background-color: #F2F2F2; color:white;text-align:center">
<p><a href="fixtures.html"><font face ="verdana">Fixtures this week</a></font>
</tr></td>
<tr style=" height:25px"><td height="25px" width="500px" style="background-color: #F2F2F2; color:white;text-align:center">
<p><a href="..."><font face="verdana">Wallpapers</a></font> <font size="0,5" color ="red"><div style="position: relative; top: -37px; left: 55px; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; ">BETA</font>
</tr></td>
</table>
```

Comment: And excuse me for my noobish code.

Comment: First of all, make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Another thing is that you have real mess in your code. At least keep content in `body` and use single `style` and properly close your brackets in css.